# Springfox: Description with headings

Tags: swagger, springfox

How can we get multiple headings inside description as following:

```
description: |
The Engine API  ....

# Errors

The API uses standard HTTP status codes ...


# Versioning

Some other text
```

In the above example, Errors and Versioning are two headers.

Currently, I am adding description as following:

```
ApiInfoBuilder().description(" ... ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with markdown like that:

```
String description = "# The Engine API  ...\n" +
        "## Errors\n" +
        "The API uses standard HTTP status codes ...\n" +
        "## Versioning\n" +
        "Some other text\n";
```

The `\n` new lines are important here.

Or simply use plain HTML:

```
String description = "<h2>The Engine API  ....</h2>" +
        "<h3>Errors</h3>" +
        "<p>The API uses standard HTTP status codes ...</p>" +
        "<h3>Versioning</h3>" +
        "<p>Some other text</p>";
```

Then add the string to the API info:

```
ApiInfoBuilder().description(description)
```